# RecylerView buffer size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner and I stumbled upon the RecyclerView. I have set up the adapter and viewholder. But there is one thing that concerns me.

If we have a very large dataset, like contacts, then how to handle the size of the dataset inside  adapter. If I keep adding the items to an list, then it will fill up memory very quickly?

Any suggestions to reduce memory usage?

Comment: `RecyclerView` will only loads number of items which are visible on screen . SO you do not worry about the memory in this case . To make this more elegant you  can have Paging in Your `RecyclerView` to load data page by page ..

Comment: But what about the buffer which which contains all the items inside the Adapter?

Comment: This data in obvious unless you are not creating extra useless objects . Having Pagination is good thing for this particular case .. For 1000 items you load 50 items per page .. So if user is only interested in top most items then you have already saved 950 Object ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right if you do not know how recycler view is working

Under the hood everything different. Whatever you are assuming is for `ListView` but in `RecyclerView` not same with `ListView`

> The RecyclerView creates only as many view holders as are needed to display the on-screen portion of the dynamic content, plus a few extra. As the user scrolls through the list, the RecyclerView takes the off-screen views and rebinds them to the data which is scrolling onto the screen.

[This link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) is very useful, to understand how `RecyclerView` is working

Answer (score 0):

firstly, RecyclerView only create the item the screen display, and it can resume the item;
Secondly, when your data is large, you should use paging, you can load a fixed items once. now you can use the component paging which in androidx.appcompat.